# ruby-on-rails debugging redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm using the following setup

Windows 7 , netbeans 7.0.1 , ruby 1.8.7 , rails 2.3.14 , redmine 1.2.2 , ruby-debug-ide 0.4.16 , mongrel 1.1.5

I try to do something very simple and I seem to have a problem with the debugger...
I have a plugin and I want to replace the the Issue done_ratio getter (my example code is Very simple for the demonstration).
When I first run the code I do get the right value (50).
Then I change the value to something else , refresh the page - and get 50 again...
When using the debugger it seems that the changes I made have no influence and the watches show the same value as before...
The dispatch.to_prepare in run on every request...

Is there no way to make it work without restarting the application?

This is my code:

```
module RedmineDoneRatioFix
  module IssuePatch
    def self.included(base) 
      base.class_eval do     
        def done_ratio
         50
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

init.rb:

```
Dispatcher.to_prepare do
require_dependency 'issue'
  Issue.send(:include, RedmineDoneRatioFix::IssuePatch)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding **unloadable** solved it:

```
module RedmineDoneRatioFix
  module IssuePatch
    def self.included(base) 
      unloadable
      base.class_eval do     
        def done_ratio
         50
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```